# How to convert JS nested some() logic to Java

Tags: javascript, java, stream

So I came across this function in some UI code that I am trying to replicate in Java to learn more about the language.

```
//dataRows is of type List<String[]> that contains lines from a csv
const hasQuotes = dataRows.some(dataRow => (
      dataRow.slice(1).some(value => value.toString().includes('"'))
    ));
```

I've been trying to figure out how I can replicate this effeciently Java, I tried using anyMatch() from stream() but I can't figure out how to nest the secondary some function within the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `java.util.stream` package. `List`s inherit a [`stream` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) from `Collection` to get a stream for the collection, and for the arrays within, you can get a `Stream` via the [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) method. Streams have [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)). So

```
final boolean hasQuotes = dataRows.stream().anyMatch(dataRow ->
    Arrays.stream(dataRow, 1, dataRow.length).anyMatch(value -> value.indexOf('"') != -1)
);
```

...or something along those lines. A slightly more verbose version:

```
final boolean hasQuotes = dataRows.stream().anyMatch(dataRow -> {
    return Arrays.stream(dataRow, 1, dataRow.length).anyMatch(value -> {
        return value.indexOf('"') != -1);
    });
});
```

---

Side note: Originally I had `String.valueOf(value)` instead of just `value` above, to be true to the JavaScript original, but if you have a `List<String[]>`, you don't need that; you *know* `value` is a `String`.

Comment: @Haq.H - No worries! Glad that helped. I just realized I was being a bit literal in the translation, see the note I've added to the end. Happy coding!